# PowerPoint not starting when debugging Office PowerPoint Add-In

Tags: visual-studio-2015, office365, powerpoint, office-addins

I started a new Office-PowerPoint-Add-In and started debug.

The IIS starts and a PowerPoint process is running, but the actual PowerPoint window doesn't show up.

When I start PowerPoint before debugging I get the error:

> Cannot debug the add-in because 'Microsoft PowerPoint' is already
>   running. Close 'Microsoft PowerPoint' and then run the project again.

I didn't have such problems with VSTO-Add-Ins.

After trying several times I got this error after starting debug:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a
>   problem in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office15\POWERPNT.EXE'.

After this error PowerPoint actually started, but the App didnt load in the task pane: error unsupported browser version.

Am I missing something? I use VS2015 & O2013.

Comment: What is your Office version and build? To find it, please open PowerPoint, click the File tab and open Account.

Comment: PPT 2013 15.0.4859.1000

Comment: That version should support Office Web Add-ins. Since the error mentions browser version, what version of IE is installed?

Comment: IE 11.09600.18449. Is Office Web Add-ins the new name? (after Office Apps & Office Add-ins) ;)

Comment: "Office Web Add-ins" is the full official name for what are commonly called "Office Add-ins" and used to be called "Apps for Office". Would you be willing to share your app manifest?